# Centering a html element using css

Tags: html, css

[image: How to center it horizontally on the page using css]

I have used a div and used margin:auto , but it does not work.

```css
#up {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="up">
  <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
</div>
```

Comment: Please add the code you have tried. Questions asking why a code doesn't work must contain that code (in your case it must be *HTML and CSS*).

Comment: #up
{
   margin: auto;
   display:block;
}<div id="up"><input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"></div>

Comment: I have tried text-align: center; but it doesn't work -thanks

Comment: @AdminRelative please edit your code into the question itself

Comment: Did you even *try* searching Stack Overflow first...there are dozens (if not hundreds) of centering questions.

Comment: Yes. I have tried those solutions

Answer (score 1):

This is duplicate question, however:

You want the input to be centered? Then add `text-align:center;` to the container div.

```css
#up { margin: auto; display:block; }
#up { border: 1px solid blue; }

#alignCenter {text-align:center;}
#alignCenter {border:1px solid purple;}

/* To illustrate what is happening */
#fileToUpload {background:red;}
```

```html
<div id="up">
  <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
</div>

<div id="alignCenter">
  <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
</div>
```